# How do you solve a tridiagonal matrix where all 3 diagonals are ones?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is probably really simple, and I'm missing something, but Thomas' algorithm doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Let's start with something simpler.  How do you solve the number 6?

Comment: Presumably "solve" = invert.  This matrix is invertible **iff**
its order is not $2\bmod 3$, in which case it has determinant $\pm 1$
and experiments such as (in **gp**) 1/matrix(19,19,i,j,abs(i-j)<2)
suggest the inverse matrix always has $0,\pm1$ entries with tractable patterns.  BTW the determinant depends on the order mod 6; perhaps
that's what Steven Landsburg was hinting at?

Comment: Noam:  You give me far too much credit!

Comment: the formula for the inverse (for an arbitrary diagonal) is here:

http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~amarti9/adfaerf/241.%20Analytical%20Inversion%20of%20Symmetric%20Tridiagonal%20Matrices.pdf

Comment: The OP should clarify what he means by "solve" - does he want to invert this matrix? diagonalize it?

Comment: the formula for the inverse $M^{\rm inverse}$ of your $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is Eq. 10 of this 1996 paper http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~amarti9/adfaerf/241.%20Analytical%20Inversion%20of%20Symmetric%20Tridiagonal%20Matrices.pdf by Hu and O'Connell:

$$M^{\rm inverse}_{ij}=-(-1)^{i+j}\frac{\cos[\frac{\pi}{3}(n+1-|j-i|)]-\cos[\frac{\pi}{3}(n+1-i-j)]}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\sin[\frac{\pi}{3}(n+1)]}$$

this paper also gives more general expressions for the inverse when you add an arbitrary multiple of the unit matrix to your $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$M=\pmatrix{0&1&-1\cr 1&-1&1\cr -1&1&0\cr} \quad N=\pmatrix{0&1&-1\cr 0&-1&1\cr 0&0&0\cr}
\quad
P=\pmatrix{0&0&0\cr 1&-1&0\cr -1&1&0\cr} $$

Then it's not hard to check that for $n=3k$, the inverse of your matrix is

$$\pmatrix{M&N&N&\cdots& N\cr P&M&N&\cdots &N\cr
P&P&M&\ldots &N\cr
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\cr
P&P&P&\cdots&M\cr}$$

For $n=3k+2$, your matrix is singular, as Noam Elkies observed in comments.

That leaves the case $n=3k+1$, which I believe is also easy, though I haven't worked it out.